Issue with docker image when trying to add group & user in alpinelinux
Not able to add group & user in alpinelinux.
I am trying to create a docker image which have alpinelinux with java 17 and glassfish server.
I need to add group and user for the application, I have tried below ways to do so but it failed.

RUN addgroup -gid 300 appuser  && useradd -m -u 300 -g appuser -s /bin/sh appuser

RUN if ! getent group appuser; then addgroup -g 300 appuser; fi 
&& if ! id -u appuser > /dev/null 2>&1; then useradd -m -u 300 -g appuser -s /bin/sh appuser; fi


Below is the issue I am facing while running the jenkins build.


As the error tells you, there is no -gid in BusyBox’s addgroup. Use -g 300 instead.

Your adduser will be erroneous too, as once again, BusyBox adduser is not the GNU one, use -G appuser (option in capital).

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.  Can you [edit] the question to replace the screen shot from Jenkins with plain-text output?  The specific numeric IDs shouldn't matter, and if the -u and -g options are causing problems, you also might try just removing them from the commands.
